# Communication complexity of approximating the size of set intersection

Tags: reference-request, communication-complexity

Consider the set-intersection problem: Alice and Bob each get a subset of $\left\{ 1,\ldots, n\right\}$, and they would like to know whether their sets intersect. This is a canonical problem of communication complexity, and it is well-known that randomized protocols for this problem require $\Theta(n)$ bits of communication ([see survey here](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~sherstov/pdf/mfcs-disjointness.pdf)). In the case where the sets are of size $k$ for $k \ll n$, it is known that randomized protocols require $\Theta(k)$ bits ([see here](http://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/HastadWi2007.pdf)).

Consider now the variant in which Alice and Bob want to know the *size* of the intersection of their sets. Clearly, computing the exact size reduces to the standard set-intersection problem, and this holds even if they only want to compute a *multiplicative* approximation of the size. However, what happens if they want to compute an *additive approximation* of the size of the intersection? Is there any lower bound or upper bound known about this problem?

I am particularly interested in this question in the setting of small sets, i.e., the case where the sets are of size $k \ll n$.

Comment: Additively c-approximating the intersection of two (n*2*c)-bit sets is at least as hard as computing the intersection of two n-bit sets; we reduce from the latter to the former by copying each bit 2c times and rounding the intersection size to the nearest multiple of c.

Comment: I suppose the following reduction from classical set disjointness to the $\alpha$-additive approximation would give you lower bound. Suppose there protocol that achieves $\alpha=f(n)$ approximation. They players duplicate each of the original $n$ bits to $3f(n)$ bits. Hence if there is no intersection, the output is at most $f(n)$, and if there is an intersection it is at least $2 f(n)$. This gives a lower bound of $\Omega(\frac{n}{3f(n)})$.

Comment: Thanks! If you turn your comments to answers I will accept them.

Comment: Don’t two subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ of size $n$ always intersect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give two upper bounds. Let $A$ and $B$ be the sets given to Alice and Bob, respectively, and put $a=|A|$, $b=|B|$, $c=|A\cap B|$.

First, there is a randomized protocol that, given $d>0$ and $\epsilon>0$, computes with probability $\ge1-\epsilon$ an approximation of $c$ up to additive error $d$, using $O\Bigl(\left(\frac{\min\{a,b\}}d\right)^2\log n\log\epsilon^{-1}\Bigr)$ bits of communication, and $O\Bigl(\left(\frac{\min\{a,b\}}d\right)^2\log \min\{a,b\}\log\epsilon^{-1}\Bigr)$ bits of randomness.

The protocol goes as follows:

1. If $d\ge\min\{a,b\}$, the party who sees it terminates the protocol and outputs $0$ as the estimate. Otherwise, Alice and Bob communicate $a$ and $b$ to each other, and determine which is smaller. I will assume below w.l.o.g. that $a\le b$.
2. Alice draws $t=\log(2\epsilon^{-1})a^2/(2d^2)$ independent uniformly random samples $a_i\in A$, $i<t$, and sends them to Bob.
3. Bob estimates $c$ as $\frac at|\{i<t:a_i\in B\}|$.

The protocol is correct by the Chernoff–Hoeffding bounds: if $X_i$ denotes the indicator random variable of the event $a_i\in B$, then $X_i$, $i<t$, are i.i.d. variables with mean $p=c/a$. Thus,
$$\Pr\left[a\overline X\le c-d\right]=\Pr\left[\overline X\le p-\tfrac da\right]\le\exp\left(-2\left(\tfrac da\right)^2t\right)\le\frac\epsilon2,$$
and similarly for $\Pr\bigl[a\overline X\ge c+d\bigr]$.

Now, these bounds are somewhat wasteful if $c\ll a$: there are also variant Chernoff bounds stating
$$\begin{align}
\Pr\left[\overline X\le p-\delta\right]&\le\exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2}{2p}t\right),\\
\Pr\left[\overline X\ge p+\delta\right]&\le\exp\left(-\frac{\delta^2}{3p}t\right),\qquad\delta\le p,
\end{align}$$
which would allow us to get by with the number of samples $t$ smaller by a factor of roughly $p$. The problem is that $p=c/a$ is the very quantity we want to approximate, hence we do not know it ahead. This can be remedied by making first a ball-park estimate of $c$.

So, the improved protocol computes with probability $\ge1-\epsilon$ an additive $d$-approximation of $c$ using $O\Bigl(\frac{\min\{a,b\}}d\left(1+\frac cd\right)\log n\log\epsilon^{-1}\Bigr)$ bits of communication, and $O\Bigl(\frac{\min\{a,b\}}d\left(1+\frac cd\right)\log \min\{a,b\}\log\epsilon^{-1}\Bigr)$ bits of randomness, and it goes as follows (the constants are not optimized):

1. Same as above.
2. Alice draws $r=10(\log\epsilon^{-1})a/d$ random samples from $A$, and sends them to Bob.
3. Bob counts how many of these samples belong to $B$, and sends this number, $s$, to Alice.
4. If $as/r\le d/2$, the protocol terminates with output $0$.
5. Alice draws $t=10sa/d$ random samples $a_i\in A$, $i<t$, and sends them to Bob.
6. Bob estimates $c$ as $\frac at|\{i<t:a_i\in B\}|$.

Without going into the details, the Chernoff bounds quoted above imply that with high probability, the value of $s/r$ is $\Theta(c/a)$, in which case the protocol does not exceed the stated cost, and it computes with high probability a good estimate of $c$ by another application of Chernoff bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! However, I just realized I forgot to mention that I am more interested in the case where the sets are small compared to $n$. Is there a way to make your protocol work in this setting?
Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: What do you mean by additive approximation in such a setting?

Comment: I would be interested in approximation up to any additive term that is meaningful, starting from a constant up to linear in the size of the sets.

Comment: But error up to a constant fraction of the size of the set is the same as multiplicative approximation, isn’t it?

Comment: Oh I see, you allow a fraction of the sizes of the original two sets, even if the intersection is much smaller.

Comment: Since this is the best answer so far, I accept it.

Answer (score 3):

[Emil's answer is clearly better and simpler if you're interested in this type of error, unless for some reason you need your protocol to be deterministic.  Oops.]

There are nontrivial protocols if you're interested in additive approximations of type $\pm \delta n$ for small constants $\delta > 0$.

For example, here's one:

1. Alice and Bob each interpret their set as a graph over $\approx \sqrt{n}$ nodes by agreeing on some canonical mapping from the $n$ possible set items to the $n$ possible edges of the graph.
2. Alice and Bob each compute a [$(k, \varepsilon)$-regularity partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szemer%C3%A9di_regularity_lemma) of their graph.
   They send each other their partition ($\widetilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$ bits) plus the density of their graph between each pair of partition sets (e.g. $\widetilde{O}_{\varepsilon}(\sqrt{n})$ bits, if densities are reported up to $\sqrt{n}$ bits of numberical precision).
3. Alice and Bob now discard edges that, for either of the two partitions:(a) have both endpoints within one of the partition sets, (b) have both endpoints between a non-regular set pair, or (c) cross a pair of sets $(S_1^A, S_2^A)$ in Alice's partition and $(S_1^B, S_2^B)$ in Bob's partition such that
   $$\max\left\{ \min\{\left| S_1^A \cap S_1^B \right|, \left|S_2^A \cap S_2^B\right|\}, \min\{\left|S_1^A \cap S_2^B\right|, \left| S_2^A \cap S_1^B \right|\} \right\}$$
   is unusually small.
   They will throw away at most a constant $\delta > 0$ fraction of the items, causing $\pm \delta n$ additive error, but $\delta$ can be made arbitrarily small by choice of $k, \varepsilon$.  The intersections among remaining items can be closely estimated by standard statistical methods, since the graphs between these sets obey the statistics of a random bipartite graph with the given density.

If this sort of approximation is interesting to you, you might get more mileage out of other graph regularity lemmas, especially Frieze-Kannan.  [Here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~spschool2016/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Rodl-Schacht.pdf) is a survey.

Comment: Thanks! The connection to regularity partitions is interesting.